# Some really weird bugs happening when while loop is executed

Tags: c++, validation, debugging, while-loop, switch-statement

So I am basically writing the Sea Battle console based game. I was actually writing the function for a game menu. It works all fine when executed, except for some weird glitches.

- When I enter an invalid **float** value, which contains numbers from 1 to 4 as its significand (for instance 7.4), it displays a standard error message but then also executes the commands corresponding to that number (7.4 will trigger an error message but then exits the program after a while as if user entered number "4" as an input, the same goes for any x.[1-4] number)
- Another weird but rather harmless glitch happens when the user enters several invalid characters of the wrong type as an input. For instance, if the user enters "!!!!!!", then the console will display an error message 6 times before asking for another input.

Here is the code fragment where problems occur. Cases 1 to 3 are not finished so they're blank for now.

```
std::cout << "Press a corresponding number for each action you want to do.\n\n1. Play Game\n2. Instructions\n3. Options\n4. Exit\n\n";
short int PlayerChoice;
std::cin >> PlayerChoice;
while (PlayerChoice != 1 && PlayerChoice != 2 && PlayerChoice != 3 && PlayerChoice != 4) // In case the user will enter the invalid/incorrect input or number
{ 
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(); // Prevents infinite loop from happening if user enters a char value
    std::cout << "Wrong input, please input a correct number between 1 and 4 (inclusive)\n";
    std::cin >> PlayerChoice;
}
switch (PlayerChoice){
case 1:
    Sleep(850);

    break;
case 2:
    Sleep(850);

    break;
case 3:
    Sleep(850);

    break;
case 4:
    Sleep(850);
    std::cout << "You have decided to exit the game.\n";
    Sleep(1500);
    std::cout << "Thanks for playing and hope to see you soon!";
    Sleep(3000);
    exit(0);
    break;
default: // This section actually isn't supposed to be executed under any circumstances
    std::cout << "Unexpected error occured. Terminating the programme.";
    break;
    }
```

Just to make it more clear, here's [the screenshot of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVNtM.png).

I am relatively new to C++, so could any C++ prof explain the nature of those bugs and give me some advices on how I can fix this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Recommendation: Construct a simple program that does nothing but get user input (a [mcve]) and work at it until you you have it beat. Your development environment should come [with a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (if it doesn't get a different development environment), a tool you can use to control the execution of your program and inspect it's variables. At the lowest level, you can execute the program instruction by instruction and see what it does and why.

Comment: Well removing "short" changes nothing. I tried to change it to char and int. But thanks I will take a look on it step-by-step and give you some more details.

Comment: `// Prevents infinite loop from happening if user enters a char value`  , well how baout if they enter 6 char values?

Comment: If someone enters 6 char values, then it displays 6 error messages (as I explained in the post above) and asks user for a valid input. Everything is okay besides an error message being displayed 6 times (as many times as there are char or special characters lol). The same bug doesn't occur when there's 6 or 7 integer numbers

Comment: Actually. You were right. Step-by-step debugging shows that in case of 8.4 it takes 8 as an input, and after executing the loop, the value of "PlayerChoice" changes to 4 and it executes loop with 4 as a new value. And in case with several "char" characters - it assign the value to 0 and then executes the loop as many times as there are characters

Comment: From what you described sounds like a valid behaviour, errors every invalid input until it gets to the first valid one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, direct use of `std::cin >> PlayerChoice;` is normally not preferred.  It does not check for user input errors.   Instead, using `std::cin.getline()` plus checking the syntax of the whole line is preferred.  For example, if the user inputs "2 3 1 5 4",  "2" will go in to trigger your option 2, but all the remaining inputs are buffered.  After that, your next `std::cin` for an integer will receive "3" without asking the user again.

It is weird to me for the results you got, but I try to explain it:

When the input 7.4 was entered, since your program instructs it to receive an integer, the `7` goes in.  And thus it prints your "wrong input...“ error message. But in the next loop, your `std::cin.ignore()`  does not clear the buffer (That's the point I don't know why.  It should, according to `std::cin.ignored()` manual.)  Then, "." is ignore, since it is not a number, and "4" goes in.  It triggers your option '4' to end the program.

In fact, if you change `std::cin.ignore()` to `std::cin.ignore('\n')`, it works.

UPDATE:
Now I know why your `std::cin.ignore()` is not doing the job:  according to the manual, if the first argument, i.e. `n`, is not provided, `n = 1`.  Thus you just ignored 1 byte.  Please read `std::basic_istream::ignore` manual.